# Alternatives to Float for margin: auto issues

Tags: html, css, css-float, centering

I'm new to web developing and made a grid of images using float:left. However I need this grid to be centered. I've been reading through a lot of questions here and know these two are an incompatible quarreling married couple. I added Display:block to all of my parent divs and widths, played around a little with clears but the grid seems to really take the float: left to heart.

What would be the proper way to have this grid while centering it within a parent div?

```
<div class="maincontent">
    <div class="imgrid"> 
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div> 
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div> 
    </div>
</div><!--main content-->
</div> <!--wrap-->
```

And the CSS:

```
.wrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background:#B90609;
}

.maincontent{
    display:block;
    width: 80%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin:auto;
    background:#8810C5;
    clear:both; 
}

.col {
    float: left;
    background:#2A17D1;
    display:block
}
.col-sm {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 1%;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
}
.col-sm img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

I also wasn't sure how to get the images on here so I attached a picture of what it looks like.

[image: How the site looks right now]

Comment: You're looking for flexbox.

Comment: Is there ever a reason to use floats over flexbox? Or floats basically outdated now?

Comment: @duckyduck - use floats for what they were originally intended - side blocks which the body text flows around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;` on the parent to create a row that wraps it's contents and centers it horizontally, and you can remove the floats.

```css
.wrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background:#B90609;
}

.maincontent{
    display:block;
    width: 80%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin:auto;
    background:#8810C5;
    clear:both; 
}

.imgrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col {
    background:#2A17D1;
    display:block
}
.col-sm {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 1%;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
}
.col-sm img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="maincontent">
    <div class="imgrid"> 
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div> 
        <div class="col col-lg col-sm"><img src="images/5_2.jpg" alt=""></div> 
    </div>
</div><!--main content-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

inline-block nested inside text-align center can be extremely useful.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:40%;height:100px;background:#ccf;">here</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:40%;height:100px;background:#cff;">you</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:40%;height:100px;background:#fcc;">go</div>
</div>
```

& here's your css tweaks.

```
.wrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background:#B90609;
}

.maincontent{
    display:block;
    width: 80%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin:auto;
    background:#8810C5;
    clear:both; 
    text-align:center; /*edit*/
}

.col {
    float: left;
    background:#2A17D1;
    display:block
}
.col-sm {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 1%;
    height: auto;
    display:inline-block; /*edit*/
}
.col-sm img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display:inline-block; /*edit*/
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: works like a charm thank you. Do you know if there's ever a reason to really use floats in place of flexbox? Or are floats outdated?

Comment: I might be the wrong person to ask. I've been using css for 20 years... And still just getting used to flexbox now. I prefer floats because I'm familiar with most of the bugs that go along with them. But flexbox is greatly useful as well. I wouldn't say floats are obsolete just yet... Table based layouts are certainly out-dated... I wouldn't be surprised if floats are next. Great question, by the way.